# Adding custom metadata field to DocuSign template

Tags: docusignapi

I need to be able to filter the templates that my organization has in docusign after I make a getTemplates API call. Right now we are filtering by folder name, but this solution is not ideal. Templates can easily get moved and the folders are created by the individual user not by organization, so every user in our organization would have to create the same folder structure.

Is there a way to add a custom data to a template? Ideally, this field would be returned with the JSON Response from DocuSign. Something like:

JSON Response from DocuSign

```
{
  "envelopeTemplates": [
    {
      "allowMarkup": "sample string 30",
      ... other standard template properties ...
      "customMetaData": {
        "foo": "bar" // what ever the user wants to add here
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or does anyone have a better idea for filtering templates?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to add the metadata to the template

- **TemplateCustom Fields** let you specify metadata that gets associated at the Template level. This data isn't visible to recipients; it's just extra metadata that you can associate with an template and query later (via API). See [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateCustomFields/) for more info.
- **Document Custom Fields** let you specify metadata that gets associated at the Document level. This data isn't visible to recipients in any way; it's just extra metadata that you can associate with a specific Document and query later (via API). See [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateDocumentFields/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add custom data to a given template by adding a "Custom Field". See here how to [Add Custom Document Fields to a Template Document](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Add%20Custom%20Document%20Fields%20to%20a%20Template%20Document.htm)